# How to update multiple columns with mutiple unique values in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

How to update multiple columns with mutiple unique values in sql server?

if i proceed with below method need to type 1000 lines manually...it's difficult..

Sample data given below: (up to 1000 rows need to update)

```
UPDATE buid
    SET Country_Code = CASE Business_Unit_ID
        WHEN 5959 THEN CA
        WHEN 930102 THEN US
        WHEN 3737 THEN CN
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

    END,
    Country_NAME = CASE Business_Unit_ID
           WHEN 5959 THEN Canada
        WHEN 930102 THEN USA
        WHEN 3737 THEN China
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    END
WHERE Business_Unit_ID IN (5959,
930102,
3737
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Unless you have a table that has the columns `No` & `Country` or something similar in-order for you to map Business_Unit_ID to Country_Name then it's impossible.

Comment: @Ephraim       You mean another table should be there with those values to get the data filtered using select query?

Comment: Indeed... You'd want to join a country codes table that has columns num, countrycode, countryname or something similar.

Comment: You need a table for mapping. Afterwards you can use an update + subquery statement. I'm pretty sure SO will be able to help you so long as you can provide that table.

Answer (score 1):

You need a table you can join with, i.e.

```
Business_Unit(Business_Unit_ID int, Country_NAME varchar(50), Country_Code varchar(2))
```

then you can do a join to update the table:

```
UPDATE b
SET b.Country_Code = bu.Country_Code
, b.Country_NAME = bu.Country_NAME
FROM buid b
INNER JOIN Business_Unit bu
ON bu.Business_Unit_ID = b.Business_Unit_ID
```